# How to make a layout center inside a background?

Tags: android

I am using a `RelativeLayout` of height 400dp and width 300dp. I want it to be in the center of a background image but I can't figure out how to do so. I have tried using `android:layout_centerInParent= "true"` but still it doesn't work. Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    tools:context=".ChooseLanguage"> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can use the **marginLeft and marginTop** commands to get it roughly in the center but it would not be the right method as what this would work only in the screen dimensions of my preview phone, it may change as the phone changes. I want it to remain in the center of the image background irrespective of the phone it is displayed on.
I am new to android studio and any help would be appreciated

Comment: have u tried using `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Comment: it works, thanks a lot. cam you please explain why doesnt centerInParent work the same way? isn't the parent of the layout the image background itself?

Comment: let me post an answer and explain it

Comment: @CSLearner Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As per my above comment You need to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554772/how-to-make-a-layout-center-inside-a-background/56554843#comment99690475_56554772)

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

The `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` will work only when the parent layout is `RelativeLayout`

Read more here about [**`android:layout_gravity`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

or

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

or

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will be to replace centerInParent with

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```